# Python - How to create an empty numpy array and append to it, like lists

Tags: python, numpy

This is something I didn't find so easily on the internet. It's easy to create `np.arrays`, but how do you create an empty one so you can append on the go?

Comment: You shouldn't do this. Numpy arrays aren't designed to change size, build the list first and then convert to an array, or initialise an empty array of correct shape and fill values by index (if the final shape is known)

Comment: But if you _did_ want to do this anyway, "numpy append" in a Google search gives [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) as the first result

Comment: You generally *don't do this* and `numpy.ndarray` objects aren't designed to allow you to do this. Numpy arrays and `list` objects have very different performance trade-offs. If you really want to do this, use a list and convert to an array at the end.

Comment: However you can stack `np.arrays` with `np.hstack` or `np.vstack`.

Comment: I've just found out that using `np.empty((0,0))` creates an empty array and then you can use `np.append()` to add items, much like lists. Do you think that's not advisable still?

Comment: No, it is not advisable at all.

Comment: Yes, because every call to append has to copy over the entire array into a new block of memory. Just because you discovered that you could initialise an empty array does not change the advice we have been giving you.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro absolutely inadvisable. `np.append` is a linear-time operation. Using it to fill a `numpy.array` will create quadratic-time behavior. In contrast, `list.append` is (amoritized) constant time, so overall, it will be linear time to construct the list.

Comment: I was just trying to figure out a hack for something that was kind of cumbersome to me, since it's sometimes tiring to go from list to arrays every time the dimensions change. And, in my opinion, for most day to day uses, it seems quite ok to sacrifice a bit of memory just for the ease of programming.

Comment: It's not memory, it's runtime too

Comment: You're not just sacrificing memory, you're taking a *huge* hit in terms of time complexity.  Beyond that, if you're trying to use numpy on lists that change size frequently, it may be time to examine why you're using `numpy`.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro no, it's a rather enormous hit to time-complexity and runtime performance. O(N) vs O(N^2)

Comment: Can someone link me to Numpy docs where they say "Numpy arrays aren't designed to change size"?  Thanks, I just want an official confirmation of its intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. A Hack

You can create an empty array using the `np.empty()` function and specify the dimensions to be `(0, 0)` and then use `np.append()` to append items later.

```py
>>> a = np.empty((0, 0))
>>> a
array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float64)
>>> b = np.append(a, [1, 2])
>>> b
array([1., 2.])
```

## 2. However...

The hack above is not advisable, use it with caution. Appending to `list`s has `O(N)` complexity, while appending to arrays has `O(N^2)` (besides different memory use). The proper way should be, then, to append to `list`s. Note that using `list()` on `numpy arrays` to transform them into `list`s is not correct, as you will get a `list` of `numpy arrays`. Instead, use the `.tolist()` method.

```py
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>>
>>> list(a)
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]
>>>
>>> a.tolist()
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score -1):

It is advised to use normal python lists and then at the end convert the list to a numpy array.

```
x = np.asarray(x)
```